# How to ask a question about a subject complement?

Tags: grammaire, questions

I would be very grateful if somebody could explain how  we can ask a question about a subject complement? E. g., what question(s) should I ask about the sentence

*Ce plat est brûlant.*

in order to get the answer *"Brûlant."*

Comment: *C'est chaud ?* / / *C'est assez chaud ?*  →*Brûlant*. // *Comment est ce plat ?* → *Brûlant* (but this one sounds weird, really out of a language exercise more than real life).  You'll probably get plenty more suggestions. If you're looking for an interrogative, in this particular instance *comment* is probably the best.

Comment: Thank you, None. I thought about using COMMENT as I came across such a question in a textbook not so long ago but there isn't a single example of such a question in a dictionary. Yet, I have found a song for learners of French named "Comment est il?" The title seems to be a question about the subject complement since it's answered with "He's intelligent" etc. Still the absence of this meaning of COMMENT in dictionaries makes me wonder if the question "Comment est il?" sounds natural. Do native speakers ever ask it?

Comment: @Val: It sounds pretty weird in English, too. "How is that dish?" "Burning hot." You expect an answer like "delicious" or 
"I've had better quiche."

Comment: Thank you, Peter. Is the same true about all similar questions? I mean, is "Comment est il?" as weird/uncommon as "Comment est ce plat?" I am still wondering about the absence of an example of such a question in dictionaries. E. g., the dictionary of the French Academy contains example questions only of "Comment allez-vous ? Comment se porte-t-il ?" type. There are no examples of questions about a subject complement with COMMENT.

Comment: Indeed after *comment* we expect a subject complement but not any would really work (same in English as Peter Shor comments).  *Comment est-il ?* (hyphenated) means "What's he like?" or "How is he?"  (asking about personality) but it really depends on context. *Comment va-t-il ?* "How's he?" (asking about health) . Dictionaries don't deal with all the subtleties of a language. In your case a lesson on *comment* (if that's what you are looking for) might be more useful. e.g. https://www.thoughtco.com/all-about-comment-1371164 // or https://www.ithinklanguages.com/french-questions-comment/

Comment: Thanks a lot, None!

Comment: @Val In real life, people rarely say sentences like *Comment est-il ?*, *Comment va-t-il ?*, or *Comment est ce plat ?*, if ever. That's textbook French, not conversational French. Maybe what a teacher expects but usual expressions would be *Il est comment ?* *Comment il va ?* *Il est comment ce plat ?*

Comment: @jlliagre I appreciate your comment, jlliagre!
 .

Comment: As a short answer is expected (brûlant), it is probably in a familiar setting. Therefore to maximize the chances of getting an answer related to temperature, I'd for example ask "C'est chaud ?" (knowing that it actually is...) "Brûlant" would be an answer of someone who does not care being too polite - because it carries a bit of a dissatisfaction.

Answer (score 2):

As the previous comments said, the most common way to ask this is to use "Comment" (= "How") :

- *"Comment est ce plat ? Il est brûlant."* (= "*How is your dish? It is burning hot.*")
- *"Comment trouves-tu ce plat ? Brûlant."* (= "*What do you think about your dish? Way too hot.*")

However, we can reformulate some questions in order to specify the kind of answer we are looking for, sometimes withouth using "Comment" :

- *"À quel point ce plat est-il chaud ? Il est brûlant."* (= "*How hot is it? Burning hot.*")
- *"La température vous convient-elle ? Non, c'est brûlant."* (= "*Is the temperature suitable? No, it's burning hot.*")
- *"Comment trouvez-vous la température de votre plat ? Brûlante."* (= "*What do you think of the temperature? It is burning hot.*"